# Dynamic Jade includes

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have this code:

show.jade:

```
foreach promo in promotions
    include _promotion
```

_promotion.jade:

```
img.thumb(src="#")
```

I'm trying to set the src of the img tag dynamically with `promo.image_url`, and I can't seem to figure out the syntax.  I've tried every combination I can think of, with no luck.  This, specifically, does not work:

```
img.thumb(src=promo.image_url)
```

I know that this works for simple tags:

```
p= promo.image_url
```

But I can't figure out how to get the = sign into the img src correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img.thumb(src="#{promo.image_url}")
```

though I hope you haven't had to wait this long!